# How to connect to SQLite database in Web Worker on Cordova / Ionic platform?

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, web-worker

How can I connect to SQLite database from Web Worker? 
This is in cordova / ionic application.

Can I use [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) or do I have to use [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/) library?

I want to Web Worker gets data from external server using API and then writes it do database. But I don't want to do that in main process.

In main process I have:

- In Angular initialization:

  ```
  .run(function($ionicPlatform, DB) {
        if ( window.cordova ) {
          DB.init();
        });
  })
  ```
- In Angular service:

  ```
  .factory('DB', function($q, DB_CONFIG, $cordovaSQLite, DebugPanel) {
      var self = this;
      self.db = null;
      self.isProduction = !!window.cordova;
      self.init = function() {
          if( self.isProduction ) {
              // self.db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: DB_CONFIG.name, location: 1});
              self.db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "db-1.db", location: 1});
          }
      };
      return self;
  })
  ```